# Disable "People with Link" sharing option at tenant level

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharing, tenant

In SharePoint Online, document "Sharing" option, Is there a way to disable "People in Tenant with the Link" sharing option at the tenant level?

2nd option in the below pic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All sharing options are listed here https://YourTenant-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/online/ExternalSharing.aspx

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.This can be disabled on a per-site collection by using PowerShell.

```
Set-SPOSite -DisableCompanyWideSharingLinks $true
```

2.Go to SharePoint admin center -> Active sites -> Select the site -> Sharing -> Set "Site content can be shared with" as "New and existing guests".